# Multiple centroid draw

Tags: neural-networks

I'm writing neural network based on neural gas algorithm (university assignment) and I remember that lecturer said that, when you generate random neuron weights at the beginning, it's worth to generate them multiple times  and choose the best set of them.

The problem: I don't know **what's the criteria of choosing the best set of weights for neurons**?

Comment: Welcome to ai.se..totally yes....unless you have some prior knowledge that the curve .like gaussian or Maxwell, then you may use weights which reflect that although I have no idea how :)